# Kafka stream with Http request

Tags: apache-kafka-streams

I want to realize the next flow of kafka stream

```
from(kafka topic) -> transform (here should be http request) -> to (kafka topic)
```

Is it correct to set http request during tranformaton in kafka stream or its more correct to use standart consumer ?

Answer (score 4):

It is possible but not recommended to do external requests within a `transform()` because the request would need to be synchronous and thus negatively impacts performance (ie, throughput).

However, if this is no concern for you it's no problem to do external request.

Comment: thanks for your answer. In which side maybe you can recommend architecture i need to see for building a good architecture in case below ?